# NSLog Java translation

Tags: java, objective-c

How do I translate the following line from Objective-C to Java:

```
NSLog(@"Current question: %@",question);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To print such to console, you can either use

```
System.out.println("Current question: " + question);
```

or

```
System.out.printf("Current question: %s\n", question);
```

Where `question` is a String.

Alternatively, you can use [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/).